# Should I use abstract class plus child class or ENUM or abstract class plus interface?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

Was solving a task that went like this
Create a tree, then create an oak, fig, pine, apple, orange tree...
Keep in mind some trees can have fruit.
Then create a forest that has trees and make all the fruittrees be gone if a fire happens.

So what I did is I have an abstract class Tree and an interface Fruitable
Depending on what kind of a tree I was just extending or extending and implementing my interface.
The only downside I see is that I had too manually put List in the Trees that implement Fruitable.
Was I right or not?
Some people in my class told me they used enums for type of trees.

Answer (score 1):

Using enums can be a practical decision in the context of a small-scale application with limited scope and simple requirements. In your case using enums can simplify and make code more readable because enums are concise and self-contained. However, they serve well when the range of options or types remains fixed and easily comprehensible.

On the other side, an object-oriented approach with inheritance and interfaces is more beneficial as the application grows. This approach provides flexibility and scalability, taking into account the changing relationships and behaviours of different types. While adding some complexity, it also assures the adaptability required for a bigger and more complicated codebase.

Even though inheritance and interfaces aren't necessary for the scope of your project, I would choose them over the enums because they are definitely more object-oriented.

Comment: Thank you, that was the reason why I didn't do it with enum because in my head we could create much more kind's of trees and then I would end up with a massive ENUM.
And the same reasoning why I went for a interfaces fruitable instead of another chilld class to not end up in the inheritance hell if the application grows. (They are teaching us not to have more then 2 child classes)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually put a list of trees that implement `Fruitable`. You can use `instanceof` check to determine it in the runtime.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Tree {
}

interface Fruitable {
}

class Oak extends Tree {
}

class Fig extends Tree implements Fruitable {
}

class Pine extends Tree {
}

class Apple extends Tree implements Fruitable {
}

class Forest {
    List<Tree> forest = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Oak(), new Apple(), new Fig(), new Pine()));
    public void fire() {
        ListIterator<Tree> li = forest.listIterator();
        while (li.hasNext()) {
            Tree t = li.next();
            if (t instanceof Fruitable) {
                li.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it like this but I didn't know I can iterate trough a List like that.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely would favor enums for this.  No need for inheritance at all:

```
public class Tree {
    public enum Type {
        OAK, FIG, PINE, APPLE, ORANGE
    }

    private Type type;

    private boolean hasFruit;

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean getHasFruit() {
        return hasFruit;
    }

    public void setHasFruit(boolean fruit) {
        this.hasFruit = fruit;
    }
}

public class Forest {
    private final Collection<Tree> trees = new ArrayList<>();

    public Collection<Tree> getTrees() {
        return new ArrayList<>(trees);
    }

    public void fire() {
        trees.removeIf(Tree::getHasFruit);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user85421 It certainly could be.  I can’t say for certain since the question didn’t specify whether specific types of trees always have fruit, though that would make sense.

Comment: Thank you all, I had a stream solution where I removed all the elements if they were instanceof Fruitable. Meaning - I complicated it. Thank you for your help.